# Angular DOM modification timing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, binding

I have a Controller, 
that change some values in the `"then"` of a barcode scanner.

First thing it set the code, then set a `"disabled"` variable, and then focus an input.

```
.then(function (barcodeData) {
    // Success! Barcode data is here                     
    $scope.selectProdotto = barcodeData;
    $scope.txtDisabled = false;
    var pageElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number], input[type=text], textarea');
    var first_element = pageElements[1];
    first_element.focus();
});
```

The input that i want to focus is ;

```
<input class='input' type='number' ng-disabled="txtDisabled" />
```

Now the problem is that the input is still disabled after i changed

```
$scope.txtDisabled = false;
```

so when i do `.focus()` it fail.

After my function finish my input is correctly enabled.

**So im asking when are variables applied to DOM ?
How can i wait for the input to be ready and enabled to focus ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you try

```
.then(function (barcodeData) {
// Success! Barcode data is here                     
$scope.selectProdotto = barcodeData;
$scope.txtDisabled = false;
$scope.$apply();
var pageElements = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=number], input[type=text], textarea');
var first_element = pageElements[1];
first_element.focus();
```

});